# Adding to an object of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an object of objects as follows:

```
var people = {
"fred": {"height": 10, "weight": 190},
"mary": {"height": 6, "weight": 120}
};
```

I want to add another item to this object. Specifically, I want to add the following object:

```
var luke = {"height": 8, "weight": 130};
```

Why can't I just do so using people.push? such as:

```
people.push(luke)
```

Comment: Alternate answer: `people.luke = luke`

Comment: The answer is that `push()` is a method for arrays, and you don't have any arrays, only objects.

Answer (score 1):

You should do

```
 people["luke"] = luke
```

or

```
 people.luke = luke
```